# Change filter depending on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with some hundreds of rows, and one Column "Color". This column "Color" can be 0 or 1. Sometimes, the column might be filled with more 1's than 0's, and vice-versa. What I want is: an expression that returns, if there are more 1's than 0's, `SELECT * FROM table WHERE Color = 0`, else `SELECT * FROM table WHERE Color = 1`. How can I do that?

Just to clarify: If there are more 1's than 0's, I want to select all the 0's. Else, do the contrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query like this one to find out which value of Color is the most popular:

```
SELECT Color FROM `table` GROUP BY Color ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Then, use this query as part of your `WHERE` condition to get the records with the other color.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE Color = 1 - (
    SELECT Color FROM `table` GROUP BY Color ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1 
)
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36d70)

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. Although, can you clarify me on why do you subtract 1 from that inner clause?

Comment: The subquery gets the most popular (1 or 0) and you want the other one (0 for 1, 1 for 0). The `1 - ()` is my lazy way of doing that. You could also do `Color <>` or change the subquery ordering from `DESC` to `ASC`

Comment: What happens if the count of '0' and '1' are equal?  Maybe the question is for the OP, as in what behaviour do they want. If the don't care whether they get '0' or '1' when it is equal.

Comment: @simo.3792095 When the count is equal, then it doesn't matter if it returns the 0's or the 1's :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select y.* from yourtable y
inner join 
(select color, count(*) count
 from yourtable
 group by color 
 order by count desc
 limit 1) c on y.color = c.color
```

We first compute the count for each `color` and then return the `color` with maximum count. We then join that `color` to the source table to get all records for that `color`.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/087c0/1)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select (case when sum(color = 0) > sum(color = 1) then 'More 0s'
             when sum(color = 0) = sum(color = 1) then 'Same'
             else 'More 1s'
        end)
from table;
```